# Getting Error 403 in Google Colab with Tensorboard with Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I have a tfevent file already present on my Drive and I have successfully connected it to Google Colab. After searching within the issues of Tensorboard Github, I found that I had to set dom.serviceWorkers.enabled to True which I have done. But on Google Colab after performing the two steps:

1. `%load_ext tensorboard`
2. `%tensorboard --logdir path/to/logs`

I am getting a Error 403 on the second step cell:[image: Error 403: google colab]

I am using Firefox version 81.0.1 (64-bit) and my default mode is Private Window, so history and cache are cleared after I close all browser window.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems that Tensorboard needs you to enable third party cookies to run without returning a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error.

I had the same issue using Chrome and fixed it by just allowing everything:

[image: screenshot cookies chrome]

You can do the same on Firefox like so:

[image: screenshot firefox tracking protection]

You could also find out which exact cookie is needed and then just allow that one.

Comment: I have enabled the third party cookies and the problem still exists , I have firefox browser installed on ubuntu system

Comment: You could check with the developer extension of your browser. Select the network tab and see if any resources could not be loaded.
I also suggest you try to open the page with a "clean" browser, meaning with no add-ons and what-so-ever installed, this way you can eliminate the browser as a source of error

Comment: I turned off the shields in the Brave browser and that fixed the 403 error. The Brave shields are accessed via the little lion head icon on the right end of your URL field of your browser. Just click on it and turn the shields switch to off.

Comment: If you don't want to allow *all* cookies, you can allow cookies on just google colab's website. 

I did this by going to 'Settings -> Privacy and security -> Cookies and other site data' on firefox and then allowing `https://colab.research.google.com`. Make sure to also click to allow `Including third-party cookies on this site`.

Answer (score 12):

For me, it worked on Firefox deactivating the **Enhanced Tracking Protection**.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me on Firefox Version 103.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same issue as I had turned on '`Block third-party cookies`' in chrome settings. Please refer to details issue threads [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3186). I tried whitelisting of "googleusercontent.com", but it didn't work.

**For Chrome**,

```
1. chrome://settings/
2. Under Privacy and security >> Cookies and other site data >> Allow all cookies
```

**For Brave,**

```
1. Turn off the shields
```

Comment: This worked for me on Chrome Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me on Chrome.
I checked it in Safari and it worked without any problem.

I found a workaround.

Execute tensorboard code twice it will give you a port number it is running.
[image]

Right click on the page and select `inspect`. Go to `Network` tab and search the same port. In my case it was `6006`.
[image]

Richt click the URL and open in a new tab and it will work.

**This is not a solution but workaround.**

Answer (score 1):

**Try clearing logs if you are sure that the logs are not useful.**

```
!rm -rf ./logs/
```

Reload the tensorboard again and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you also have to untick the 'Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed' option in Settings.